# Does the Activity need to be Serializable when sending a class that implements Serializable through Intent and putExtra?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, serialization

I have been trying to pass an instance of a class from one Activity to another.

So far, I have only gotten `java.io.NotSerializableException` exceptions.

At first, these were linked to the class I set to extend Serializable, and when these errors stopped they started linking to the Activity from where I send the instance through Intent and putExtra.

Here is the code that causes an issue:

```
Intent i = new Intent(NewGame.this, GameActivity.class);
i.putExtra("existing", true);
i.putExtra("customClass", gh);<--- THIS is the line for the Serializable class I send
startActivity(i);<--- Here I get NotSerializableException
```

The NotSerializableException first linked to NewGame(the activity where the Intent is located), and after I then tried to extend serializable it starts to show errors on fields such as Button and RadioGroup(View-extending).

If I make NewGame not implement Serializable, I am back to NewGame as the Activity where the intent is being sent from being the problem.

So:

Does `i.putExtra(String name, Serializable s)` require the Activity where the Intent is sent from to implement Serializable? If no, why does startActivity give me an exception on the Activity I am sending the intent from?

More code:

```
public class NewGame extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener, SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener,
        RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener, AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, Serializable{
    SeekBar sb; 
    TextView tvAI;
    Button start, custAI;<--- This gives an error for some reason
    int max = 9;
    int min = 1;
    int step = 1;
    RadioGroup uniSize, aiDiff;<--- This gives an error for some reason
    Spinner spinner;<-- This gives an error for some reason
    int diff = 0;
    public void onCreate(Bundle sis){
        super.onCreate(sis);
        setContentView(R.layout.startgame);
        initialization of etc views
    }

    //Irrelevant code between create and onCreate is removed

    private void create(){


        setContentView(R.layout.loading);

        Thread thread = new Thread() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    super.run();
                    sleep(500);  //initial tiny delay
                    //GameHandler implements serializable
                    GameHandler gh = new GameHandler(stars, NewGame.this, AIs);//The GameHandler constructor takes in: int, Context, int
                    (etc other code)
                    gh.initGen(ais, player);
                    gh.save();

                    IntentHandler i = new IntentHandler();
                    Intent i = new Intent(instance, GameActivity.class);
                    i.putExtra("existingGH", true);
                    i.putExtra("gameHandler", gh);<--- This is where the app would stop if the issue is related to fields in GameHandler(gh)
                    instance.startActivity(i);<--- THIS is where the app stops working. It shows an exception related to the fields of NewGame(the class the intent is sent from and this code is in)
                    Log.e("DEBUG", "Leaving Activity NewGame");
                    finish();
                    join();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };
        thread.start();
    }

}
```

GameHandler:

```
public class GameHandler implements Serializable{

    int stars;
    int AIEntities;
    private Context c;
    private int width, height;
    private Random r;
    private Game game;
    private Neutral n;

    /**
     * Load the game.
     * @param c
     */
    public GameHandler(Context c, Game game){
        this.game = game;
        this.c = c;
        (etc irrelevant code)

    }

    public GameHandler(int stars, Context c, int AIEntities){
        this.c = c;
        this.stars = stars;
        this.AIEntities = AIEntities;

        (etc initialization)
        ais = new ArrayList<>();


    }
    public void initGen(ArrayList<Entity> ais, Player player){
        this.ais = ais;
        this.player = player;

        generate();
        //
        save();
    }

    public void save(){
        //saving
    }

    Rect[] rect;
    private int sx, sy, sclas, smass;
    ArrayList<Stars> solar;
    public void generate() {
        ...
    }

    public ArrayList<Stars> getStars(){
        return solar;
    }

    public void render(Canvas c){
        //rendering
    }

   //Needs to be transient to avoid error(Entity causes error)
    public transient ArrayList<Entity> ais;
    (other code, not relevant)

}
```

StackTrace:

```
     03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = com.mypackage.game.GameHandler)
03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1468)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1416)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:686)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1330)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1079)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:711)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:8778)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.startActivity(ActivityManagerNative.java:3112)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1540)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4283)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4230)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4567)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4535)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at com.mypackage.NewGame$3.run(NewGame.java:320)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err: Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: com.mypackage.NewGame
03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1344)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeFieldValues(ObjectOutputStream.java:959)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:360)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeHierarchy(ObjectOutputStream.java:1054)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeNewObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1384)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObjectInternal(ObjectOutputStream.java:1651)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1497)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1461)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:     at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:1463)
            03-25 18:42:46.371 1423-2474/com.mypackage W/System.err:    ... 13 more
```

Comment: please give complete code(Serialize class and next class where send data) for more understanding then we suggest any way for resolve issue

Comment: The receiving class is not an issue. The exception is caught @ startActivity in NewGame and shows exceptions on NewGame fields(thus asking if the Activity needs to be Serializable). GameHandler does now show any exceptions and does not contain any of the relevant fiends either. I am adding relevant code from NewGame.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does i.putExtra(String name, Serializable s) require the Activity where the Intent is sent from to implement Serializable?

No, but it *does* mean that `s` cannot refer to the activity or other non-`Serializable` stuff *or* you will need to take steps to prevent the serialization from trying to serialize them (e.g., override the methods described [in the documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/Serializable.html)).

> it is triggered on objects in the NewGame class, which does not have an instance in gh

Yes, it does. It is right here:

```
private Context c;
```

First, `Context` is not `Serializable`. Second, `Activity` inherits from `Context`, and `c` is your `NewGame` activity, because you assign that to `c`.

Comment: What I find weird about the exceptions is that it is triggered on objects in the NewGame class, which does not have an instance in gh(the class I am trying to send to a different Activity)

Comment: Updated the question, see the code I took from the ACtivity. Looking for the StackTrace, going to add that in a second

Comment: @LunarWatcher: "which does not have an instance in gh" -- well, you are passing one into the `GameHandler` constructor.

Comment: The instance passed into the constructor is not stored in GameHandler. It is used in the constructor for basic initialization, then it is disposed of. I don't think that would cause a problem

Comment: Edit: Passing NewGame is for the Context. The GameHandler constructor is `int, context, int`

Comment: @LunarWatcher: "It is used in the constructor for basic initialization, then it is disposed of" -- yes, but anything that you initialized from it might hold a reference back to it. With no code for `GameHandler`, and with no stack trace, it will be difficult to help you further.

Comment: Edited to add GameHandler and the stacktrace

Comment: Context is not serializable, but with the `transent` keyword the issues are solved.